# Matching probe IDs from Data expression file to Gene annotation file with WGCNA

Tags: regex, r

I have a microarray data expression file which contains top ranked genes(with probe IDs).I wanted to match them with the probe IDs present in Gene Annotation file.Now the problem is, Gene Annotation file contains the same probe IDs but in uppercase e.g. 200738_S_AT  . And in data expression file it looks like:  200738_s_at. I tried with this function-

```
       grep(dat_expr_probe_IDS, Gene_annot$probeIDs, ignore.case=TRUE,value=TRUE)
```

But it only returns one probe ID with this warning-

```
      argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I increase the pattern length to match them all?

Data expression file looks like this-

```
                            probe IDS

                         1  202958_at
                         2  203050_x_at
                         3  217980_s_at
                         4  225265_at
                            ...
```

Gene annotation file example is here-

```
                            probe IDS

                         1  202968_AT
                         2  203050_X_AT
                         3  217981_S_AT
                         4  225265_AT
                            ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `grep(paste(dat_expr_probe_IDS, collapse='|'), Gene_annot$probeIDs, ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)`  (untested). Also, when you post, please show some example data to test the code and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .but it didnot work correctly.For example I have 10 IDs in data expression file but after matching with annotation file it showed 12 ,which is not correct.Atmost it could be 10 not more than that.I hav eadded the file example ,may be you can try now.waiting for a solution!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: got the solution already                compare(dat_expr_probe_IDS,Gene_annot$probeIDs,allowAll=TRUE). :)